# How do I solve a problem .map is not a function React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React problem. I'm trying to add an array of objects to my App.js file and to use the map method. But for some reason there is an error message - .map is not a function. What can I do to fix it?

App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";
import menu from './data.js';
import Menu from './Menu.js';

function App() {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(menu);
 

  return (
    <main>
      <section className='menu section'>
        <div className='title'>
          <h2>Our menu</h2>
          <div className='underline'></div>
        </div>
      
        <Menu menu={menuItems}/>
      </section>
    </main>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Menu.js file:

```
import React from 'react';

const Menu = ({menu}) => {

    return <div className="section-center">
        {menu.map((menuItem)=>{
            const {id, title, price} = menuItem;
            return <article key={id} className="menu-item">
            <div className='item-info'>
                <header>
                    <h4>{title}</h4>
                    <h4 className="price">{price}</h4>
                </header>
                
            </div>
            </article>
        })}
    </div>
}

export default Menu;
```

data.js file, where my array of objects is stored:

```
const menu = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "tomatoes",
      category: "veg",
      price: 160,
      img: "../SITE/img/tomatoes.jpg",
    },
    
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "kiwi",
      category: "fruit",
      price: 130,
      img: "../SITE/img/kiwi.JPG",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "cabbage",
      category: "veg",
      price: 15,
      img: "../SITE/img/cabbage.jpg",
    },
]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you import the data file into the Menu file? How would it recognize the menu object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export your `menu` as below

```
export default [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "tomatoes",
      category: "veg",
      price: 160,
      img: "../SITE/img/tomatoes.jpg",
    },
    
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "kiwi",
      category: "fruit",
      price: 130,
      img: "../SITE/img/kiwi.JPG",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "cabbage",
      category: "veg",
      price: 15,
      img: "../SITE/img/cabbage.jpg",
    },
]
```

The above one is for a `default export`. Or else, you can `export` different data elements after naming them inside your `data.js` file and import them as you need like below,

```
export const menu = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "tomatoes",
      category: "veg",
      price: 160,
      img: "../SITE/img/tomatoes.jpg",
    },
    
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "kiwi",
      category: "fruit",
      price: 130,
      img: "../SITE/img/kiwi.JPG",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "cabbage",
      category: "veg",
      price: 15,
      img: "../SITE/img/cabbage.jpg",
    },
]
```

and import it as below,

```
import { menu } from './data.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `export` keyword before `const menu` in data.js file.

Answer (score 0):

`{menu}` makes menu into an object. Whatever data structure is in your `menu`, `{menu}` will make it into

```js
{
  menu: "your menu data structure"
}
```

You should either extract `menu` from the object or use the raw `menu` Array like `const Menu = menu => {`.